# Como faço caso o usuario digite um número diferente de 1 e 2 ele pergunte deseja encerrar o programa?\n[1] para sim e [2] para nao

Tags: c

Como faço caso o usuario digite um número diferente de 1 e 2 ele pergunte deseja encerrar o programa?\n[1] para sim e [2] para nao

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int N1, N2, Q, R, OP;
    {
    do
    {
    printf("DIVIDINDO DOIS NUMEROS: \n\n");
    printf("Digite o dividendo: ");
    scanf("%d", &N1);
    printf("Digite o divisor:   ");
    scanf("%d", &N2);
    Q = N1 / N2;
    R = N1 % N2;
    printf("\nResultado:       %d\n", Q);
    printf("Resto:            %d\n", R);
    printf("\n\nDeseja encerrar o programa?\n[1] para sim e [2] para nao.\n");
    printf("\nOpcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &OP);
    printf("\n \n");
    }
    while (OP == 2);
    if (OP >= 1)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    system("PAUSE>>NULL");
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Evitar encerramento ao digitar valores diferentes de 1 e 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305908/evitar-encerramento-ao-digitar-valores-diferentes-de-1-e-2)

Comment: Não só é duplicata como é o mesmo usuário perguntando a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está quase correto, só precisa de algumas alterações, a lógica e essa enquanto for diferente de 2 ele vai repetir, também daria para fazer com looping infinito mas não é muito legal de se fazer

Seu código corrigido

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int N1, N2, Q, R, OP;
  do
  {
    printf("DIVIDINDO DOIS NUMEROS: \n\n");
    printf("Digite o dividendo: ");
    scanf("%d", &N1);
    printf("Digite o divisor:   ");
    scanf("%d", &N2);
    Q = N1 / N2;
    R = N1 % N2;
    printf("\nResultado:       %d\n", Q);
    printf("Resto:            %d\n", R);
    printf("\n\nDeseja encerrar o programa?\n[1] para sim e [2] para nao.\n");
    printf("\nOpcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &OP);
    printf("\n \n");
  }
   while (OP != 2);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```