# Como faço caso o usuario digite um número diferente de 1 e 2 ele pergunte deseja encerrar o programa?\n[1] para sim e [2] para nao?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() 
{
int var1, var2, Q, R, decisao;
    printf("Dividindo dois numeros\n\n");
    printf("Digite o dividendo: ");
    scanf("%d", &var1);
    printf("Digite o divisor: ");
    scanf("%d", &var2);
    Q = var1 / var2;
    R = var1 % var2;
    printf("Resultado: %d\n", Q);
    printf("Resto: %d\n", R);


    printf("\nDeseja encerrar o programa?[1] para sim e [2] para nao..\nOpcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &decisao);

    if(decisao == 2)
        return main(); 

        if(decisao ==1);
        exit (0);


        system("PAUSE>>NULL");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cara eu mesmo respondi essa pergunta, você não viu ?

Comment: já existe uma pergunta igual [nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306363/como-faço-caso-o-usuario-digite-um-número-diferente-de-1-e-2-ele-pergunte-deseja/306393#306393)

Comment: Esta é duplicada das outras duas, [evitar-encerramento-ao-digitar-valores-diferentes-de-1-e-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305908/evitar-encerramento-ao-digitar-valores-diferentes-de-1-e-2) e [como-faço-caso-o-usuario-digite-um-número-diferente-de-1-e-2-ele-pergunte-deseja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306363/como-fa%C3%A7o-caso-o-usuario-digite-um-n%C3%BAmero-diferente-de-1-e-2-ele-pergunte-deseja)

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() 
{
int var1, var2, Q, R, decisao = 2;
while(decisao == 2){
    printf("Dividindo dois numeros\n\n");
    printf("Digite o dividendo: ");
    scanf("%d", &var1);
    printf("Digite o divisor: ");
    scanf("%d", &var2);
    Q = var1 / var2;
    R = var1 % var2;
    printf("Resultado: %d\n", Q);
    printf("Resto: %d\n", R);


    printf("\nDeseja encerrar o programa?[1] para sim e [2] para nao..\nOpcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &decisao);
}
        printf("\nPrograma finalizado");
        system("PAUSE>>NULL");
        return 0;
}
```

Repare que adicionei um "while", ou seja, enquanto o número que o usuário digitar for igual a 2, a repetição irá continuar.
Também ao declarar a variável "continuar" foi atribuído o valor 2

Seria melhor fazer a repetição dessa forma:

```
char ch = 'S';

while(ch == 'S' || ch == 's'){
**FAÇA**

printf("Para continuar pressione "S" para sair digite qualquer outra tecla");
ch = getch();
}
```

para usar o **getch();** seria necessário incluir a biblioteca **conio.h**

Answer (score -3):

```
//Use a fução 
main()
{
     do
     {
          _________
          _________
          _________
          _________
     }while(decisao==não)
}
```

//Usando isso, o que estiver dentro 'do' só vai acontecer enquanto for igual a não, mas isso é só o básico. Vc tem que saber strings para fazer o q eu estou dizendo.